# How do I fix / prevent text in GNOME toolbar to be truncated/shorten?

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell, text

When I have many indicators in GNOME Shell 3.28.3 (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS), the text shown by some indicators are getting truncated / shorten.  Here is an example where the clock frequency of the CPU and date become shortened:

[image: GNOME toolbar with text shortened]

Anybody has a solution to the problem?  Does this happens also with the latest version of GNOME?

**Update:**  Still occurring in Gnome 3.34 as of 2019-12-03.